# Can I change the image path in Jekyll Post?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Post images are basically pulled from the assets folder.
However, the image in my post is structured as follows.

```
_posts
  Docker
    assets
      images
        2021-05-21-Dockerfile
          FROM-command.png
          RUN-command.png
    2021-05-21-Dockerfile.md
```

`./assets/images/2021-05-21-Dockerfile/FROM-command.png`
With Jekyll's default settings, the image path of the post is specified as in the form above,
how do I change it to the form below?
`./Docker/assets/images/2021-05-21-Dockerfile/FROM-command.png`
Where `Docker` is the category name of the post.

I registered defaults in the following way, but it doesn't work.

```yaml
#_config.yml

defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "_posts/:categories/assets/images/:title/"
    values:
      permalink: /:categories/assets/images/:title/
```

Comment: How do you reference your image in html / markdown? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter `relative_url`, see [docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/).

You can also use abslout paths

`![My Image](https://...)`